# Rails return null for Float column

Tags: oracle12c, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have an Oracle Table with columns of type **Float** and I am using Ruby on Rails to retrieve data from that table. Data for float columns can be saved in Oracle with no problem but when retrieving, the data are coming as nil. I am using '*activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter*' version 1.6.7 to connect to Oracle.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by oracle-enhanced contributors.

**issue:**
https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/1244

**solution:**
https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/pull/1254